# A way to add a constraint between two domains in a table without using a trigger?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008, constraints

I have a following table, `Client`.

```
create table Client (
    ClientID    int identity primary key,
    TaxID       varchar(12),
    SSN         varchar(12)
)
GO
```

Client can have either TaxID or SSN or both. But either one should exist.
Currently, I am enforcing the rule thru following trigger.

```
create trigger trgClient_UniqueTaxIDSSN
    on Client
    after Insert, Update
as
    --; Check if either TaxID or SSN is not null.
```

*But is there a way to declare a **constraint** to enforce the rule?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE Client ADD CONSTRAINT ck_TaxIDorSSN CHECK 
    (TaxID is not null or SSN is not null)
```

Comment: @Adam: Thanks Adam.  I was playing around with creating a check constraint in-line within `CREATE TABLE`.  I wasn't aware of declaring a `CHECK` constraint thru `ALTER TABLE`.  Right now I was creating a function to pass to CHECK constraint, which was kind of fruitless.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create a Check Constraint, on the Client table, to do this.

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx
```

Answer (score 1):

A [CHECK constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179491.aspx) that checks for null with a boolean OR would seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [Check constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179491.aspx) that checks for null in either field:

```
ALTER TABLE Client ADD CONSTRAINT cn_TaxIDorSSNnotNULL CHECK 
  (TaxID IS NOT NULL OR SSN IS NOT NULL)
```